# Grunt Qunit-Tests - Only if assertions fail: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing QUnit start() call

Tags: gruntjs, phantomjs, sapui5, qunit, grunt-contrib-qunit

I am using Grunt to run Qunit tests for a SAPUI5 application. Here is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-qunit");

  grunt.initConfig({
    qunit: {
      all: ["OpaMatchers.html"]
    }
  });
};
```

When all my (currently two) specs pass, I get the expected Output

```
.OK
>> 2 assertions passed (11606ms)
```

However, If only one of them fails I get:

```
>> PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing QUnit start()
Warning: 1/1 assertions failed (0ms) Use --force to continue.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did copy the OPA5 specs from another source. Since I wronte a set of completely new ones, the error above can not be replicated.

Comment: Were you able to identify the cause for the issue ? Now, i face the same when any of the test fails.

Comment: For anyone else running into the same problem, the following answer should help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/34928952